# Time control bar for animation in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-animation

On the matplotlib [website](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/animations.html), all examples to create animation include this control bar:

[image]

Which allows one to precisely select the time, to stop, and to play the animation in the desired direction. The code they provide, however, does not create such a control bar. Do you know how to make one? I have found several workarounds, I was wondering if there is a simple way to do it.